# How has detective Bosch earned his money to buy his house?

Tags: bosch

In one of the first episodes of the TV series *Bosch*, the main character's daughter, Maddie, asks her father jokingly "is he on the take", since he can afford such a nice place. As an answer, Bosch points to a movie poster saying "at least they haven't used my real name".

In the *Bosch - legacy* series, the matter of the movie poster comes again when Maddie asks her father "was he ever shot". He admits that he indeed was, during some joint-op shootout, that was looking like from an action movie, after which he again points at the poster.

So was Bosch an actor at some stage? A consultant?

Comment: No. They made a movie based on one of his cases. I believe they paid him for the story and as a consultant on the movie. I'm on mobile so I can't dig up the exact quote.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, that would make sense. I must have missed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Bosch* in-universe movie, *[The Black Echo](https://harrybosch.fandom.com/wiki/The_Black_Echo_(film))* is based on at least one case Bosch (and Maddies's mother Elonor Wish) was involved in. He eventually explains the case to Maddie in *Bosch: Legacy* 1.06 (Chain of Authenticity).

### **Bosch: Legacy 1.06 Transcript**

> Harry: I was part of an LAPD FBI joint task force. We were working a
> string of bank robberies and murders. Bad guys were using the tunnels
> that run under the city to pull off their capers.
>
> Maddie: Oh, man, that sounds like something out of a movie.
>
> Harry: [CHUCKLES] Yeah.
>
> Maddie: Is that...?
>
> Harry: Needless to say, they completely f*cked it up.
>
> Maddie: That's how you bought the house.
>
> Harry: Yeah.

So they made a movie very loosely based on a case Bosch was working on and he used **the money from consulting on the film** to buy his modern cliff-side L.A. home.

However, the confusion may come from the out-of-universe trivia that one of the Harry Bosch books from author and executive producer Micheal Connelly is also named *[The Black Echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Echo)*. It along with elements from two other Connelly Harry Bosch books were the basis for plots of Bosch's [third season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosch_(TV_series)).

Comment: Why is does “murder” have a * in it?

Comment: @Darren I do not know, but I will fix it.